# Github: ¿Puedo desde un pipeline (Actions), ejecutar y hacer pruebas en un codespace configurado?

Tags: github, pipeline

Instalé ns3 en un codespace, y funciona sin problemas, pero quiero que se ejecuten pruebas, cuando alguien de mi equipo realice un pull_request.

¿Hay manera de configurar esto?
¿O que otra solución, alternativa podría considerar?

Ejecutar el pipeline accediendo al Codespace pre-configurado

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.